# Find the nearest number(but not exceed) in the list and change numbers in the series(Python)

Tags: python, pandas, series

there is a **series** like below

```
s = pd.Series([25, 33, 39])

0    25
1    33
2    39
dtype: int64
```

and **a list**

```
list = [5, 10, 20, 26, 30, 31, 32, 35, 40]

[5, 10, 20, 26, 30, 31, 32, 35, 40]
```

I'd like to find the **nearest number** in the list and **change the number **in the series

for example
first number is the series is 25
but the list is [5, 10, 20, 26, 30, 31, 32, 35, 40]

so the firtst nearest number(corresponding to 25 in the series)
is 20 (Actually 26 is nearest number, but I need a number less than 25)

and then the second number is 31, thrid is 35
after finding the number and change that in the series

**desired out s** is

```
0    20
1    31
2    35
```

please give me advice. It's a very important task for me.
if possilbe?  without for loop plz

Find the nearest number(but not exceed) in the list and change numbers in the series(Python)

Comment: The result for 33 would surely be 32, not 31.  Right?  Why do you say "without for loop"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `merge_asof`:

```py
s = pd.Series([25, 33, 39], name="s")
l = pd.Series([5, 10, 20, 26, 30, 31, 32, 35, 40], name="l")

pd.merge_asof(s, l, left_on="s", right_on="l")
```

A few notes:

- There is a bug in your expected output. The closest number to 33 is 32.
- Don't name your variable `list`. It overwrites the name of a very common Python class.
- Make sure `l` is sorted.